# Toast Error message, but The Application is still running the code

Tags: android, error-handling, toast

I have a problem in  Android studio which is, When i input a number on a EditText,  i just want a number between 1 to 5, the problem is when i input 6,  toast message is show an error message correctly, but the code still run and continue to process number 6, that shoud be an errror, what should i do?

```
    public void doSomeWork(){
if (tahunAngka < 0 || tahunAngka > 5) {
            //error message
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Must Enter a Number Between 1 - 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (bulanAngka < 0 || bulanAngka > 11) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Must Enter a Number Between 1 - 12", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: post your code with toast

Comment: kindly post your code.

Comment: disable your edittext after showing toast to user simple

Comment: Here the code,,,

Comment: where is your code

Comment: '
        if (tahunAngka < 0 || tahunAngka > 5) {
            //error message
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tahun Yang Anda Masukkan Tidak Sesuai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
'

Comment: EditText tahunUsia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEditUsiaTahun);

//then i get that EditText with this code :

private usiaTahun;

usiaTahun = tahunUsia.getText().toString();

//then i parse to integer 

Integer tahunAngka = Integer.parseInt(usiaTahun);

Comment: i dont know what to say.. im bad on english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need like this:

```
public void doSomeWork() {

   String usiaTahun = tahunUsia.getText().toString();

   // check value is empty
   if (!usiaTahun.isEmpty()) {

       // parse string to integer
       int tahunAngka = Integer.parseInt(usiaTahun);

       // check value is in between 0 to 5
       if (tahunAngka < 0 || tahunAngka > 5) {

           // error message
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tahun Yang Anda Masukkan Tidak Sesuai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

           // do your code here if number is in between 0 to 5

        }

   } else {

       // error message
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }

}
```

Call this `doSomeWork()` in you button's `onClick()` method.

Comment: what if there are two statement are the same , am i using "if else" two times>

Comment: First "if" statement is to check whether the string value is empty or not. If the value is not empty, parse the string value to a integer. Second "If" statement is to check whether the value is in between 0 to 5. So you're using it two times

Comment: Great  Fikru

Comment: Thank you! Mark it as answered if your issue solved.

Comment: What should i do.? It is my firs time using stack overflow,,  ;v

Comment: You can select the check mark beside the answer. Refer here: [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Well done Fikri

Comment: I mean Fikru 